# SailsJs dynamic router not returning req parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Is there anything wrong with this router in SailsJs? It is returning `req.allParams is not a function`. req itself is {}. I am following the [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes) but it doesn't log the name parameter as it should.

Router:

```
'/qqq/:name':  { action: 'project/view-project' },
```

Controller:

```
module.exports = {
  fn: async function (req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.allParams()))
    return res.success();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason after multiple hours of looking... Need to use `this.req.allParams()` instead of `req.allParams()`